# Why draught beer tastes so different at different places in India

Tags: specialty-beers, draught

I just want to know why draught beer tastes so different at different places in India. I have been to different places all over the country and the beer tastes radically different.

Comment: You need to narrow your question down. You say "draught" beer? Which brand? Is it all the same brand or different brands? There are also different styles of beer. I am going to vote to close this question unless this is cleared up.

Comment: Do you mean the same beer tastes different in different places, or are you perhaps encountering regional styles that would taste different no matter where you drink them?

Comment: Let close this unless the question is narrowed

Comment: I'm putting this on hold temporarily.  Please [edit] to narrow the question down (see previous comments) and we can review for reopening.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the water. The water has a big role in the beverage's taste.

Comment: The thing is, the draught beer which is available here in Kolkata (eastern India) is produced by a single company which monopolizes the business in India- UB group (Kingfisher). Then???

Comment: @SouparnoAdhikary , they have several breweries across India.

Comment: Hi Mixhab, it would be useful if you could expand your answer to explain what in, and how water can impact the taste of beer.

Answer (score 0):

It's many smaller factors but the most likely if it's the same brand are the following:

Storage temperature: in shipping and storage large temperature swings or storage above cellar temperature increase the ageing process of the beer dramatically. In extreme cases of hot temperatures spoilage bacteria, as well as chemical changes, are even more prone to happen.

Draft line cleaning: every bar has different ages on their lines as well as different cleaning standards. In high end beer bars, line cleaning is encouraged every two weeks. This removes mineral buildup as well as destroys bacteria growth in plastic lines for a time. These buildups or bacterial produced off flavors will be different to each location and can easily ruin beer, or at least change its intended flavor.

Comment: What you wrote is true but doesn't accurately answer the question. Usually when the same company has numerous breweries/factories, it uses the same methods and ingredients for manufacturing and moving its products. The only thing that is different is the water. This is also the reason why certain beverages taste different in each country. Take Coca-Cola for example - the formula is exactly the same everywhere but the water is different in each country. This is the reason why the taste is a bit different in each country.